# ORA 01861 error

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I am reading a date from a linked serve and it returns the field in the datetime2 format.  Here is my simplified query:

```
select * from openquery(LinkedServer,
    'select QCTL.INVC_HEADER.POST_DATE
    FROM  QCTL.INVC_HEADER ')
```

When I copy one of the records returned by the query to use it as input parameter, I get an `ORA 10861` error:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

```
    select * from openquery(LinkedServer,
    'select QCTL.INVC_HEADER.POST_DATE
    FROM  QCTL.INVC_HEADER 
    WHERE
    QCTL.INVC_HEADER.POST_DATE < ''2004-09-03 00:00:00.0000000''')
```

Please advise how to get around this

Comment: Try a proper timestamp literal: `timestamp ''2004-09-03 00:00:00.0000000'''`, don't rely on the evil implicit data type conversion

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with the hard-coded date. You can't simply put it as literal on Oracle (unlike SQL Server).

- You can try using a `TO_DATE()` conversion function:

  ```
  select * from openquery(LinkedServer,
      'select QCTL.INVC_HEADER.POST_DATE
      FROM  QCTL.INVC_HEADER 
      WHERE
      QCTL.INVC_HEADER.POST_DATE < TO_DATE(''2004-09-03'', ''YYYY-MM-DD'')')
  ```
- Placing the `timestamp` keyword just behind the literal will make it work also.

  ```
  select * from openquery(LinkedServer,
      'select QCTL.INVC_HEADER.POST_DATE
      FROM  QCTL.INVC_HEADER 
      WHERE
      QCTL.INVC_HEADER.POST_DATE < timestamp ''2004-09-03 00:00:00.0000000''')
  ```